# IBM Worklight - Using SQLite in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am learning IBM Worklight. I have implemented an `SQLAdapter` with DB2 as my database on my laptop.

But I could not find any tutorial regarding "How Connect `SQLAdapter` with `SQLite`" in Android emulator. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In addition to Idan's answer, do you mind me asking what exactly you are trying to do? Attempting to connect to an SQLite database (client local storage) from a Worklight adapter (server side call from the client) throws up a couple of red flags.... If you're looking for a local storage solution for a hybrid app then I'd suggest Worklight's built in JSONStore: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/05_08_JSONStore_-_The_client_side_JSON_based_database_overview.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you do not use Worklight adapters in conjunction with SQLite.

Worklight adapters are a means to deliver data from and to an **external** backend system (like your DB2 database).

In order to interface with SQLite in your device you use straight forward JavaScript and SQL.

- For example: [Cordova Storage API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Storage)

Comment: Yes... Cordova (PhoneGap) 2.6 is bundled with Worklight, it is core part of Worklight. Please also learn how to use Worklight: http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/library/