# IBM Worklight retrieving data from SQLite to MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am developing a Worklight Android native app. I have a local database - SQLite to store some data and I want to transfer the data to server-side MySQL database. I am using Worklight SQL Adapter for communication with MySQL but as long as I know the adapter is not usable for retrieving local data. How can I make the transfer from the local database to the remote one? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use adapters for accessing local DB. however you can fetch the data using native way and send the same to SQL adapter to save it in MySQL database.

For more info

- If you are using Hybrid use [Coredova API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Storage)
- SO [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838104/ibm-worklight-using-sqlite-in-android)
- if you are only using native code see this [Article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html) get the data and send it to WL adapter by [invoke procedure](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/07_02_Using_Worklight_API_in_native_Android_applications.pdf)

AFAIK there is no way to send data's from SQLite to backend DB. you can do the above workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually looked into the documents and all I could find was example for Hybrid application and JavaScript code. I assumed that in a Native app there is no place to put the JavaScript code. Could you give some insight?

Comment: I hope your are using these [methods](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/07_02_Using_Worklight_API_in_native_Android_applications.pdf) to call worklight procedure. In that case get the local DB data first using native code then pass the same data to Adapter.

Comment: Yes, I am using exactly these methods. Currently I am trying to get the local data, passing it is the easy part :). Thank you again for the quick answer